# Is possible to reuse app name again if it's renamed in Appstore?

Tags: ios, ios5, app-store-connect

Hi i want rename my app and use previous app name after sometime? Is this possible?

Comment: I *think* what ultimately matters is the application ID, but Apple may not approve an app if there's another app with the exact same name in the app store. Can you rename the old app first and then submit your new app with a different application ID and the reused name next?  Do you have access to that Apple App Store account where the original app (the one with the name you want to recycle) is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can - as long as you were the original owner of the previous app name.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can.

If you can't do it right away then it will probably become available after the 120-day limit that Apple  has for reserving app names on the store.